# Move the folder from checklistbox 1 to 2 using vb.net

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net

I have two checklistbox. One is the folder list I want to copy. And second one is the location list I want to copy the folder to.

The thing is I do not know how to click the checklistbox and move to the location. All I have been done is to set a fix location, and I can copy from folder test to folder. but I want to choose the tick in checklist and move from box 1 to box 2, not the fixed location and folder.

```
Private Sub moveContainerToLocation_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles moveContainerToLocation.Click
    'To do
    Try
        Dim fileToCopy As String
        Dim NewCopy As String
        Dim fileSize As Long


        ' fileToCopy is folder i want to move 
        ' NewCopy  is the location what we choose to move the folder to



        fileToCopy = "C:\folder test"
        NewCopy = "C:\folder"
        fileSize = GetFolderSize(fileToCopy)

        ' allow to overwrite
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(fileToCopy, NewCopy, True)
        Timer1.Start()
        moveContainerToLocation.Enabled = False


        ' the percentage of files transferred and use it into the progressbar
        Dim counter =Directory.GetFiles(fileToCopy,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
        'Next
    Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
    End Try
End Sub
```

''this is to get my folder in my checklistbox1

```
Private Sub GetfolderButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetContainerButton.Click

    For Each dra As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\folder test")
        Container.Items.Add(dra)
    Next

End Sub
```

''this is to get my location in my checklistbox1

```
Private Sub getLocationButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles getLocationButton.Click

    For Each dr As String In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\folder")
        Location.Items.Add(dr)
    Next



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking how to get the checked items in a `CheckedListBox`, right? The first thing is, that there can be potentially multiple checked items in a CheckedListBox`. So you won't get a single answer.

```
If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Please select something")
    Return
ElseIf CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox("Please select only one item")
    Return

End If

NewCopy = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0)
```